# How can I fix vector scale in quiver2D in R oceanview package?

Tags: r, scale, vectorization

```
rm(list = ls())
library(RNetCDF)
library(rgl)
library(plot3D)
library(plot3Drgl)
library(OceanView)

vec_surf_field=TRUE

###
### read variables(lon,lat,u,v)
###

u2<-array(0,c(120,110,30,120))
v2<-array(0,c(120,110,30,120))
vec2<-c(0:9)
for(j in vec2){
  readname="/data1/kimyy/oman_restore_04_18/197"
  readname2="12/ocean_snap_197"
  readname3="12.nc"
  rname=paste(readname,as.character(j),readname2,as.character(j),readname3,sep="")
  nc2 <- open.nc(rname)
  u2_temp<-var.get.nc(nc2,"u");
  v2_temp<-var.get.nc(nc2,"v");
  temp2_temp<-var.get.nc(nc2,"temp")
  eta_t2_temp<-var.get.nc(nc2,"eta_t")
  lon2<-var.get.nc(nc2,"xt_ocean");
  lat2<-var.get.nc(nc2,"yt_ocean");
  level2<-var.get.nc(nc2,"st_ocean");
  ilevel2 = -level2

  for (i in c(1:12))
  {
    u2[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),1:length(level2),j*12+i]<-u2_temp[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),1:length(level2),i]
    v2[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),1:length(level2),j*12+i]<-v2_temp[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),1:length(level2),i]
    temp2[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),1:length(level2),j*12+i]<-temp2_temp[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),1:length(level2),i]
    eta_t2[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),j*12+i]<-eta_t2_temp[1:length(lon2),1:length(lat2),i]
  }
}


###
###  surface vector field
###

if (vec_surf_field==TRUE)
{
  for (l in c(1:120))
  {
    year=as.character(as.integer((l-1)/12))
    month=as.character(l-as.integer((l-1)/12)*12)
    if (as.integer(month)<=9) {
      filename=paste("/data1/kimyy/oman_restore_04_18/gif/vec_surf_field/197",as.character(year),"0",as.character(month),".png",sep="");
      gifname=paste("Surface Vector (", as.character(year),"year ",as.character(month),"month)",sep="");
    } else {
      filename=paste("/data1/kimyy/oman_restore_04_18/gif/vec_surf_field/197",as.character(year),as.character(month),".png",sep="");
      gifname=paste("Surface Vector (", as.character(year),"year ",as.character(month),"month)",sep="");
    }

    png(file=filename,width=1300,height=1100)
    par(mar=c(9,10,7,7), mgp = c(7, 3, 0))
    #par(mar=c(10,11,8,8), mgp = c(8, 4, 0))
    quiver2D(u=u2[1:120,1:110,1,l],v=v2[1:120,1:110,1,l], x = lon2, y = lat2, 
             colvar = sqrt(u2[1:120,1:110,1,l]^2 + v2[1:120,1:110,1,l]^2), clim = c(0, 0.5), col="black",
             main = paste (gifname), xlab = "Degrees East (°E)", ylab = "Degrees North (°N)",
             arr.max = 0.15, arr.min = 0.15, clab = "Speed (m/s)", scale=2.5, by=4, NAcol="white", asp=1,
             cex.axis=3, cex.main=3.5, cex.lab=3, colkey=NULL)
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

that code has this process
1. read the 120 monthly data
2. plot 120 surface vector field

in that process, I can't fix the vector(arrow length) scale.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmWiM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGiY3.png)

as you can see the difference of two pictures,
vector scale is different.
would you help me solve this problem?

ps) in matlab, I can solve this 'quiver(x,y,u,v,'AutoScale','off');